# Error in na.fail.default: missing values in object

Tags: r, r-caret, bag

I am getting the following error when trying to do a 10-fold cv in caret.

> "Error in na.fail.default(list(Date = c(18178, 18177, 18176, 18175, 18172, : missing values in object"

I have reviewed the code manually and there are no missing values. Additionally, my model isn't even looking at the Date variable, but the error and it's traceback clearly show that R is trying to include it.

I'm at a loss on what to do as this wasn't an issue using `ipred` for bagging. Is it a quirk of the caret package or am I just not using the caret arguments correctly?

```
require(caret)
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv",  number = 10) 

# CV bagged model
require(caret)
bagged_cv <- train(
  formula = Cease ~ flow_2 + flow_3 + flow_4 + flow_5 + flow_6 + flow_7 + flow_8 + flow_9 + flow_10,
  data = flow_train,
  method = "treebag",
  trControl = ctrl,
  importance = TRUE
  )
```

Just noting that it makes no difference whetehr I use Cease ~. -Date or use the method above to include everything except the Date variable. I still get the same error message.

```
Error in na.fail.default(list(Date = c(18178, 18177, 18176, 18175, 18172, : missing values in object
10.
stop("missing values in object")
9.
na.fail.default(structure(list(Date = structure(c(18178, 18177, 18176, 18175, 18172, 18171, 18169, 18168, 18167, 18166, 18165, 18164, 18161, 18160, 18159, 18158, 18157, 18155, 18154, 18153, 18152, 18151, 18150, 18149, 18147, 18145, 18144, 18143, 18142, ...
8.
(function (object, ...) UseMethod("na.fail"))(structure(list(Date = structure(c(18178, 18177, 18176, 18175, 18172, 18171, 18169, 18168, 18167, 18166, 18165, 18164, 18161, 18160, 18159, 18158, 18157, 18155, 18154, ...
7.
model.frame.default(data = flow_train, na.action = na.fail)
6.
stats::model.frame(data = flow_train, na.action = na.fail)
5.
eval(expr, p)
4.
eval(expr, p)
3.
eval.parent(m)
2.
train.formula(formula = flow_train$Cease ~ . - flow_train$Date, data = flow_train, method = "treebag", trControl = ctrl, importance = TRUE)
1.
train(formula = flow_train$Cease ~ . - flow_train$Date, data = flow_train, method = "treebag", trControl = ctrl, importance = TRUE)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the "method above" is. I'd suggest trying to remove the column prior to starting the analysis.   It's hard to help without a reproducible example. Can you try to create the smallest possible data set that generates the error and add that?